# MapBox GL JS: Get lat and long coordinates from string Address that is set through code

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, coordinates, mapbox

I am using **Mapbox GL JS** to show certain location marked on the map.
I need to ***set location through JavaScript code*** and I don't know the lat and long coordinates, **I only have an address in string form (example: "address, city, country" or some similar format)**.

I have searched a lot on the internet, but the only way that I have found for doing this in Mapbox GL JS is by using Geocoder input control, but I don't want to input location through it, **I want to set Address through code** and then have it marked on map when the map loads.

Is it possible to do this in Mapbox GL **without knowing lat and long coordinates**? How can I do that?

Thanks in advance! Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Mapbox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/) without the Geocoder control. You have to compose your url (and encode it).
Always consider you could get more than one result in the featureCollection response depending your params, so finally you have to refine the results with some of the attributes allowed such as `proximity` and `limit`. At the beginning is a bit of try and error task, but after some practice it's quite accurate.

Here you have an example url for the address [`123 Main St Boston MA 02111`](https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/123%20Main%20St%20Boston%20MA.json?country=US&access_token=PASTE_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE), filtering the results in United States only.

```
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/123%20Main%20St%20Boston%20MA.json?country=US&access_token=PASTE_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
```

This will return 5 streets in the Massachusetts state.
[image]

I recommend you to read the documentation in [forward geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/), and also the section on [address geocoding format](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/address-geocoding-format-guide/) to compose properly the url.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried to do this before, but I am not sure to which property in code should I set this URL...Do you maybe know where should I set it in code?

Comment: Thank you very much! I just made a GET request using Axios (I used my API key of course) to a similar URL and it got the job done. Best regards!

Comment: You can also use a simple JavaScript [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for your async request tot he URL